# Inconsistency in size of array cells

Tags: c, windows, sorting, binary-search

i'm doing a school project implementing some sorting algorithms in C codes, and i'm working on a Binary Insertion Sort on some generic data type arrays (so i'm using `void*` items and `void**` arrays).

I have a `binarySearch` function that returns the index i would have to insert an item into the array to preserve the ordering of its elements (according to a given function that i pass to the sorting function), and this works correctly.

```
int binary_search(void **arr, void *item, long start, long end, int data_size, compFunc compare)
{
  int s = start, e = end;
  while (s <= e)
  {
    long middle = s + (e - s) / 2;
    int comparison = compare(item, arr[middle]);
    if (comparison == 0)
      return middle;
    else if (comparison > 0)
      s = middle + 1;
    else
      e = middle - 1;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Then i have the `binaryInsertSort` function

```
void binary_insert_sort(void **arr, long arr_size, int data_size, compFunc compare)
{
  long explored, j, pos;
  void *current = malloc(sizeof(void*)), *holder;
  if(!current){
    perror("Error allocating memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  for (explored = 1; explored < arr_size; explored++)
  {
    memcpy(current, arr[explored], data_size);
    j = explored - 1;
    pos = binary_search(arr, current, 0, j, data_size, compare);
    while (j >= pos)
    {
      holder = malloc(sizeof(void *));
      memcpy(holder, (*arr) + (j + 1)*data_size, data_size);
//CRASHES HERE
      memcpy((*arr) + (j + 1) * data_size, (*arr) + (j * data_size), data_size);
      memcpy((*arr) + (j * data_size), holder, data_size);
      j--;
      free(holder);
    }
  }
  free(current);
}
```

I call these functions like this

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char* arr[] = {"a", "b", "f", "d", "c", "g", "e", "1"};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(char*);

    binary_insert_sort((void**)arr, n, sizeof(char*), string_compare);
    print_string_array(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

But it always crashes after the first `memcpy` , when i try to move `arr[j+1]` into `arr[j]` ; i tried doing some debugging and, after trying to print `(int)(arr[1]-arr[0])`(which should print the size of a cell if i understand correctly), i noticed cells have size = 2 rather than the expected `sizeof(char*)=4` , so there are problem accessing them correctly when using `*arr + j*data_size` , since i'm moving `j * 2` cells rather than `j`

why does this happen?

i apologize if i'm missing something basic, or if english or formatting arent right, 1st time asking

Comment: Welcome to SO. `memcpy(current, arr[explored], data_size);` You only allocate `sizeof (void*)` bytes of memory for `current`

Comment: `void *` is a specific, complete data type.  Elements can *point to* objects of any (object) type, but the elements themselves are not generic.

Comment: Re “`(int)(arr[1]-arr[0])`(which should print the size of a cell if i understand correctly)”: No. `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are elements of the array `arr`. Those elements have type `char *`. They are initialized to point to various strings, `"a"`, `"b"`, and so on. Those element values are essentially unrelated; one element of the array can point to a completely different place in memory than another element, just as an array of integers can contain 37 after 5. The values they get depend on where the compiler puts the strings, and it is largely free to arrange the strings it memory…

Comment: `(int)(arr[1]-arr[0])` Why do you think this results in any size of any "cell". Instead it will subtract 2 pointers using pointer arithmetics. As these pointers don't point into the same array, doing calculations with them is illegal.

Comment: I don't understand why you are performing any dynamic allocation or `memcpy()` at all.  As written, you are trying to sort an ordinary array of pointers (to void).  For swapping (the pointers), all you need is an automatically allocated temporary of type `void *`, and ordinary assignment statements.

Comment: … So if `arr[1]-arr[0]` is 2 or 4, that just means the compiler put the string that `arr[1]` points to 2 or 4 bytes in memory beyond where it put the string that `arr[0]` points to (assuming the subtraction works in the plain way). It has nothing to do with any cell size.

Comment: If what you really wanted to do was sort arrays of arbitrary element type, then you might want to review the signature and semantics of `qsort()`, the C standard library's canonical function for that purpose.  Working an exercise or two to understand how to use that correctly might help you better understand how your own function should work.

Comment: @Gerhardh true i missed that, so i should malloc(data_size), but shouldn't it still work in this particular case, given that char* and void* have same size?
about the pointer subtraction, i dont understand why it's not right: after all, when accessing cells via arr[i], are we not implicitly adding the offset (i) to the value of *arr = arr[0]? again, i despise c because i know i dont get it fully so i might be completely wrong

Comment: @JohnBollinger so i can replace all memcpy with simple '=' assignments? and when you talk about "automatically allocated temporay of type void*" you mean simply declaring it as void* temp, with no malloc call?

Comment: @EricPostpischil i think i got it mixed up, i was assuming that (int)(arr[0]) would give me the address of the cell '0' of the array, not the content

Comment: @GTess, provided that you really do mean to sort an array of `void *`, not an array of objects of a type chosen at runtime, then yes to both questions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i'm sorry i dont think im following you, my array is an array of void* that **should** be pointing to data of generic types, so i'll have to use the algorithm of arrays of ints, strings, and various structs; the cast to void* was made (in my mind) to allow generic types, but this is my first c exercise of this kind so im pretty sure i messed up in many places, as the comments pointed out

Comment: @GTess, as I wrote before, there is a big difference between the elements being of type `void *` and *pointing to* objects of a type that may differ between calls, and elements *being* of a type that may differ between calls.  As implemented, your sort function handles only arrays with elements of type `void *`, but the appearance of a data size in your function signature and your use of dynamic allocation and `memcpy()` in the implementation suggest that you might have intended the other alternative.  You'll have to tell me which one you really mean.

Comment: Perhaps this will distinguish: is your function supposed to be usable for sorting an array of `int`?  That is, `int array[NUM_ELEMENTS] = { ... }; binary_insert_sort(array, ...);`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i'm doing a school project implementing some sorting algorithms in C codes, and i'm working on a Binary Insertion Sort on some generic data type arrays (so i'm using void* items and void** arrays).

You clarified in comments that what you mean is that you want a function that can sort arrays having any element type.  This is exactly what the standard library's [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function does, so you should look to it for guidance on how such a function might look and work.

In particular, you need to understand that C has no generic data type.  In particular, a `void *` can *point to* an object of any type, but `void *` itself is a specific, complete type, not generic in any way.<sup>*</sup>  Thus, using `void *` items does not serve your purpose at all.  Not even if you wanted to sort only arrays of pointers, because the C language does not guarantee that different pointer types have the same representation as each other, or even the same size, except only that `char *` and `void *` are required to have the same size and representation.

In other words, no, you don't have `void *` items, and you don't want to sort a "`void **` array".  And therefore no, your `binarySearch()` function for an array of `void *` does not serve your purposes -- however well it does its job, it's the wrong job.

Following `qsort()`, here's a signature that would serve your purpose:

```
typedef int (*compFunc)(const void *, const void *);

void binary_insert_sort(void *arr, size_t element_count, size_t element_size,
        compFunc compare);
```

Note that the array to sort is conveyed via a pointer to its first element, received by the function as a pointer of type `void *` -- not `void **`.  This does present an issue, however: you cannot perform pointer arithmetic or array indexing on a `void *`, because these operations are defined in terms of the size of the pointed-to type, which is unknown in this case because `void` is an incomplete type.  But it should not be a particular surprise that such an issue arises, because the whole point of the exercise is to sort objects whose size is not known when the the function is compiled.

So what do you do?  The traditional approach would be via converting to `char *`:

```
#define ELEMENT_POINTER(base, index, size) ((char *) (base) + (index) * (size))

void *element_3_for_example = ELEMENT_POINTER(arr, 3, element_size);
```

So a comparison would then look like this ...

```
int result = compare(ELEMENT_POINTER(arr, i, element_size),
                     ELEMENT_POINTER(arr, j, element_size));
```

... and a swap might look like this:

```
void *temp = malloc(element_size);

// ...

memcpy(temp, ELEMENT_POINTER(arr, i, element_size));
memcpy(ELEMENT_POINTER(arr, i, element_size), ELEMENT_POINTER(arr, j, element_size));
memcpy(ELEMENT_POINTER(arr, j, element_size), temp);

// ...

free(temp);
```

I'll leave it to you to work the actual exercise in terms of those or similar constructs.

---

As for the actual question ...

> why does this happen?

, it's because your function is confused about whether the elements of the array are themselves the items being sorted or whether they are pointers to the elements being sorted.  Erroneously assuming the latter, it makes the further questionable choice of swapping the data instead of the pointers.  In this particular case, the data happen to be pointers after all, though that would not always be the case. The data they point to are arrays containing string literals, and

1. These arrays are not the expected size, so you have bounds overruns on both reading and writing, and
2. They are not writable anyway, which is probably the specific source of the error.

---

<sup>*</sup> One could consider `void` to be a generic data type, as indeed this answer could be taken to demonstrate. But you cannot declare an object to have type `void`, nor access an object via an lvalue of type `void`, so this is largely moot.

Comment: Thanks so much for the extensive answer, i had a hunch i was messing up big time but wasnt sure where, i'll read carefully what you wrote and try to understand and implement it. May i ask why the standard approach is converting to char*? 
Also, in your element_3_for _example code, after the assignment the variable is holding the pointer pointing to the cell which begins the 3rd element of the array, or what? I'm still a bit confused, trying to absorb what i didnt know

Comment: @GTess, the traditional approach involves converting to `char *` because pointer arithmetic works in units the size of the pointed-to type. By definition, the size of `char` is 1 in these units.  Because `void` is an incomplete type, it has no size, therefore C does not define pointer arithmetic involving type `void *`.

Comment: Some C implementations do accept pointer arithmetic with `void *` as an extension, and treat it as if by automatically converting to `char *`, but it is better not to rely on that.

Comment: thanks to your suggestions i now have implemented some code that seems to work, as in its correctly sorting an array of int and of struct {int; char*} (i can order this both according to the int or the string field); i tried to do the same with just a string array but this time it's not working, and thanks to some debug prints i put here and there it seems like when he's comparing and trying to find the correct position, he's actually comparing the pointers to the string (as in the addresses, if that makes sense). How can i post the code without creating a new thread?

Comment: @GTess, the new problem you describe would probably arise from an error in your comparison function for the string case.  If you cannot figure it out and want to ask here then you *should* ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, i found where it broke. thanks so much for the continued help

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is initially wrong due the function declarations and their calls like for example

```
binary_insert_sort((void**)arr, n, sizeof(char*), string_compare);
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is if within the function you will dereference the pointer like for example

```
arr[explored]
```

then the expression will have the type `void *`. So if the original array has for example the type

```
char arr[] = "hello";
```

then in the expression above there will be used incorrect pointer arithmetic. That is instead of evaluation the value of the pointer expression like `value of arr + explored * sizeof( char )` the value of the pointer expression will be evaluated like `value of arr + explored * sizeof( void * )`.

Also the function is inefficient. There are too many memory allocations in the while loop

```
while (j >= pos)
{
  holder = malloc(sizeof(void *));
  //...
```

The function should be declared at least like

```
void binary_insert_sort( void *arr, size_t arr_size, size_t data_size, compFunc compare);
```

The function `binary_search` has a redundant parameter `start`. You are calling the function always passing 0 as its argument for the parameter start

```
pos = binary_search(arr, current, 0, j, data_size, compare);
```

Instead of the parameters `start` and `end` it is enough to pass the number of elements in the sub-array. So the function could be declared like

```
int binary_search( const void *arr, const void *item, size_t arr_size, size_t data_size, compFunc compare);
```

Or similarly to the standard C function `bsearch` like

```
int binary_search( const void *item, const void *arr, size_t arr_size, size_t data_size, compFunc compare);
```

If the sub-array already has the element that is equal to the searched element then the function should return the position after the existent element in the sub-array instead of returning the position of the existent element.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to the help of the previous comments i managed to get it somewhat going, here is the updated code

```
#define GET_PTR(base, offset, size) ((char *)(base) + (offset) * (size))

long binary_search(void *arr, void *item, size_t end, int data_size, compFunc compare)
{
    long s = 0, e = end, middle;
    int comparison;
    while (s <= e)
    {
        middle = s + (e - s) / 2;
        comparison = compare(item, GET_PTR(arr, middle, data_size));
        if (comparison == 0)
            return middle;
        else if (comparison > 0)
            s = middle + 1;
        else
            e = middle - 1;
    }
    return s;
}

void swap(void *base, long ind1, long ind2, size_t data_size)
{
    void *temp = malloc(data_size);
    memcpy(temp, GET_PTR(base, ind2, data_size), data_size);
    memcpy(GET_PTR(base, ind2, data_size), GET_PTR(base, ind1, data_size), data_size);
    memcpy(GET_PTR(base, ind1, data_size), temp, data_size);
    free(temp);
}

void binary_insert_sort(void *arr, size_t arr_size, size_t data_size, compFunc cmp)
{
    void *current = malloc(data_size), *holder;
    long explored, shifting, bs_pos;
    for (explored = 1; explored < arr_size; explored++)
    {
        current = GET_PTR(arr, explored, data_size);
        shifting = explored - 1;
        bs_pos = binary_search(arr, current, shifting, data_size, cmp);

        while (shifting >= bs_pos)
        {
            swap(arr, shifting, shifting + 1, data_size);
            shifting--;
        }
    }
    free(current);
}
```

and this seems to work, it manages to correctly sort an array of int and of a 'Person' struct when called like this

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // char *string_arr[] = {"a", "b", "f", "d", "c", "g", "e", "1"};
    // int char_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    // print_string_array((char**)arr, char_size);
    // binary_insert_sort((void*)arr, char_size, sizeof(char*), string_compare);
    // print_string_array((char**)arr, char_size);


    int int_arr[] = {5, 3, 2, 4, 0, 6, 14, -4, 0, 32, 2, -1};
    int int_size = sizeof(int_arr) / sizeof(int_arr[0]);
    print_int_array((int*)int_arr, int_size);
    binary_insert_sort((void*)int_arr, int_size, sizeof(int), int_compare);
    print_int_array((int*)int_arr, int_size);


    Person p_arr[] = {{3, "fabio"}, {5, "marco"}, {0, "giulio"}, {2, "alberto"}, {1, "gabri"}};
    int p_size = sizeof(p_arr)/sizeof(p_arr[0]);
    for(int i =0;i<p_size;i++) print_person(&(p_arr[i]));
    // binary_insert_sort(p_arr, p_size, sizeof(Person), person_int_cmp);
    binary_insert_sort(p_arr, p_size, sizeof(Person), person_string_cmp);
    for(int i =0;i<p_size;i++) print_person(&(p_arr[i]));

    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason, the string array just wont sort: i put some debug prints and to me it seems like the problem is that when i compare them, what's really being compared is their address, as the value of `comparison` in binary_search is always 1 when it's sorting `char_arr`

Here are the functions being used:

```
typedef struct {
int id;
char* name;
} Person;

int person_int_cmp(void* p1, void* p2)
{
Person *a = (Person*)p1;
Person *b = (Person*)p2;
return a->id - b->id;
}

int person_string_cmp(void* p1, void* p2)
{
Person *a = (Person*)p1;
Person *b = (Person*)p2;
return strcmp(a->name, b->name);
}

void print_person(void* p){
Person* a = (Person*)p;
printf("%d: %s\n", a->id, a->name);
}

int string_compare(void *a, void *b)
{
char * str1 = (char *)a;
char * str2 = (char *)b;
return strcmp(str1, str2);
}

int int_compare(void *n1, void *n2)
{
int n01 = *(int *)n1, n02 = *(int *)n2;
return n01 - n02;
}

void print_int_array(int *arr, long size)
{
printf("\t[");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) printf("%d -> ", arr[i]);
printf("]\n");
}

void print_string_array(char** arr, long size)
{
printf("\t[");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) printf("%s -> ", arr[i]);
printf("]");
}
```

Am i treating the string array in some wrong way i am not aware of? What's even weirder to me is that it's able to correctly sort the Person array by the names (which are strings) but not an array of just strings
If anyone can point me what i'm doing wrong thanks so much